# GoogleMap does not display

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to load the GoogleMap. I use the `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` library and this is the xml for the MapView.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyDvTjB5XuzifATB4G50qBc7TTRo5luhV9o"
    />
```

My activity extends the `MapActivity as public class Geofencesetup extends MapActivity {}`.But when I run the code, I got only small small grids, can't see the Map. 
My application has two xmls, one has fragment for another Map display application as follow

```
 <fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

I want to add in the MapView as it is nicer for making Overlay for Geofencing setup. For the fragment, I can see the whole map, but for the MapView I see only the grid.
My query is 
(1)Can I use `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` and `com.google.android.maps.MapView` in the same application?
(2)Why I see only grids at the MapView?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to use both API's in the same application. Even if you could do that then you can't use `Google Map API V1` with it's `MapView` and `MapActivity` object as this API was already deprecated by Google and you can't get a new `API` key for it. this is probably the reason you see only a grid instead of a map.

So it's encouraged and recommended to move your application to use only the `Google Maps API V2`.

Comment: Thanks, if like this how to make overlay on the GoogleMap. I can't find getOverlays() API at GoogleMap map;

Comment: Unfortunately this option is not available in Google Maps API V2. To paint lines on the map you should use Polyline object.

Comment: How can I implement for the user interface on the GoogleMap like using the Overlay? When the user touch a point on the map that is one corner of a rectangle and the user drag and release. The last point where the user touch the map is the another corner of the rectangle. The rectangle is paint with a half transparent color. That can be implemented easily using the MapView. How to implement on the Google Maps API V2. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: The most close thing you can do is to listen to onMapClick and paint a Polygon as a result: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon

Comment: Thanks I got some clues from the discussion with you. Waste of time working on the MapView. I'll use onMapClick and a Polygon. Thanks